# graph $G=(V,E)$ with $i(G) > |V|/2$

Tags: graph-theory

Dominating set for a graph $G = (V, E)$ is a subset $D$ of $V$ such that every vertex not in $D$ is adjacent to at least one member of $D$. The domination number $γ(G)$ is the number of vertices in a smallest dominating set for $G$.

Independent set is also a dominating set if and only if it is a maximal independent set, so any maximal independent set in a graph is necessarily also a minimal dominating set. Thus, the smallest maximal independent set is greater in size than the smallest independent dominating set. The independent domination number $i(G)$ of a graph G is the size of the smallest independent dominating set (or, equivalently, the size of the smallest maximal independent set).

I need a graph $G=(V,E)$ with $i(G) > |V|/2$.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Take the graph $G = (V,E)$ with $V = \{a,b\}$ and $E = \emptyset$. Then, $i(G) = |V| = 2$.

**edit:** For a non-trivial example, consider the following graph:

[image]

Suppose $W \subset V$ is independent and dominating. If $W$ does not contain $A,B$ or $C$, it mus contain all outer vertices and it follows that $|W| = 9$. If $W$ contains one of the inner vertices ($A,B$ or $C$), it cannot contain the other two and hence must contain the 'other' 6 outer vertices. In this case $|W| = 7$.

It follows that $i(G) = 7 > 6 = |V|/2$.